# Monte Carlo simulation using modified rejection technique

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, homework

> Plot the probability density function
>
> $\qquad w(x)=(1/(1+x^2))(1/x^{0.5})$ for $(0 < x < 1)$
>
> Make up the subroutine flowchart to get the random numbers $x$, using the modified rejection technique with first factor used as the comparison 
>   function.
>
> Use the flowchart to get a few random numbers in Wolfram Mathematica

Trial answer:

```
a = 0; b = 1;
f[x_] := (1/(1 + x^2)) (1/x^0.5)
h = 1; Nt = 1000000;
gr1 = Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]

S := (
  x = y = b h; 
  While[y > f[x], 
    x = a + (b - a) RandomReal[]; 
    y = h RandomReal[]]; 
  Return[x];
)

rez = Table[S, {i, Nt}];
gr2 = Histogram[rez, Automatic, "PDF"]
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

Comment: There is no question here, I'm afraid. What are you having trouble with? BTW, this sounds pretty obviously a homework assignment of some sort, right?

Comment: I don't think `w(x)` integrates to 1 over the interval (0,1).  Do you mean `Sqrt[2]/pi w(x)` integrated from zero to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

Taking @mjw's correction into account and rewriting your code like so

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[2]/π/((1 + x^2) Sqrt[x])

a = .0001; b = 100;
gr1 = Plot[f[x], {x, a, 5}, PlotRange -> All];
S :=
  Module[{x, y, h = 1.},
    x = y = b h;
    While[y > f[x],
      x = RandomReal[{a, b}];
      y = h RandomReal[]];
    x]
gr2 = Histogram[Table[S, 1000], Automatic, "PDF"];
Show[gr2, gr1, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, Sqrt[2]}}]
```

produces

[image: plot]

which seems fairly satisfactory.